# Java generics: Clean way to process two generic types using one function signature

Tags: java, generics

There is a class `Utilities` which offers public static functions, to do generic data processing. The class is mainly used to create `FloatPointer`s to be used in native code.

The class looks like this:

```
class Utilities
{
    private Utilities(){}

    static FloatPointer toPointer( List< TypeA > list )
    {
        // do some magic
        return p
    }

    static FloatPointer toPointer( List< TypeB > list )
    {
        // do some different magic
        return p
    }
}
```

The problem with this is obvious. Because the compiler resolves these signatures to `FloatPointer toPointer( List list )` I get an erasure issue, so these functions cannot be defined like this.

Now I am asking myself, what is the cleanest way to implement this.

Firstly, I would very much like to stick with the name `toPointer` instead of using varying function names. This is because in the real class there is a whole bunch of these `toPointer` functions dealing with various types. Introducing a new name will break the scheme and since other developers on the team are used to `toPointer` this is not a good idea.

I can imagine there to be two functions `private static typeAToPointer( List< TypeA > list )` and `private static typeBToPointer( List< TypeB > list )`, but these two would need to be called from a public `toPointer` function as to not break the scheme of function names.

Sadly we do not implement `TypeA` or `TypeB`, so I cannot let the two implement a common interface and accept that - in general I cannot change `TypeA` or `TypeB` in any way.

Currently I tend to implement a function accepting a `List< T >` and simply check type, then deal with that. This routine would look something along the lines of this:

```
static < T > FloatPointer toPointer( List< T > list )
{
    Class clazz;
    if( !list.isEmpty() ) clazz = list.get( 0 ).getClass();
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Empty list will result in NP." );

    if( clazz == TypeA.class ) return typeAToPointer( list );
    else if( clazz == TypeB.class ) return typeBToPointer( list );
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException( "List entries of invalid type." );

}
```

To me this looks like awful code. Am I mistaken there? What would be an elegant/clean way of achieving my goal, *i.e.* keep the function call `toPointer`, but process either generic list, all while being unable to temper with the definitions of `TypeA` or `TypeB`?

Comment: What is the "magic" you need to do? Is it the same (ish) for both?

Comment: "To me this looks like awful code. Am I mistaken there?" Your judgment is correct.

Comment: Yes and no, The code is samish, but the two types do have different public functions which I need to use. Sadly I cannot accept the generic Type `T` and then deal with it in the same fashion. Have to differentiate.

Comment: Please show the magic. The form of the answer depends on what it actually needs to do.

Comment: The magic is to create a float array, then transfer entries from `TypeA`, `TypeB` respectively into that array. How much memory I need to allocate depends on `T`. How I iterate over the List and fill my array depends on that too. `TypeA` and `TypeB` are vector types each of which is not part of the standard Java library, but JME. I need to treat this data C++ side.

Comment: As mentioned, I do not like this solution either which is why I am looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: I know it's not what you're looking for, but the cleanest way I can see of doing this is Java is simply to change the method name rather than overloading. I know it's not *ideal*, but it's certainly a hell of a lot cleaner than the `toPointer()` example you've got there, and also keeps the generic type safety.

Comment: If the 2 (or more) types of list are semantically distinct, does it really make sense to use generics?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Java, but in Kotlin you _might_ be able to alias each distinct List type, and pass them around via their aliases instead... aaaand that probably doesn't get around erasure. What about wrapping them in distinct non-generic boxes?

Comment: Go for `Utilities.toPointerTypeA` / `toPointerTypeB`. I think that `FloatPointers.fromTypeA` / `fromTypeB`, would be nicer, though, but that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @Marco13 I like the idea of refactoring `FloatPointer` to do these conversions, maybe I will look into that.

Comment: @AjahnCharles Generics only came up, because erasure prevents method overload, as shown in the example above. If you have another idea - go ahead. The project is large and multiple people are working on it, so I am definitely not shifting it to Kotlin. ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me this looks like awful code. Am I mistaken there?

No, you're not mistaken. The example there is messy, unclear, performs unnecessary checks at runtime and isn't able to check any type safety at compile time either.

That being said:

> What would be an elegant/clean way of achieving my goal, i.e. keep the function call toPointer, but process either generic list, all while being unable to temper with the definitions of TypeA or TypeB?

...you can't.

Java generics are implemented via erasure, so the generic information is all lost at runtime (there's no concept of it in the bytecode.) That means that you can't have two methods whose signatures differ only in their generic types, as the JVM would have no way of distinguishing between them at runtime.

Despite your reluctance, the cleanest, most obvious way of achieving what you're after is simply to relax your requirement that the method names must be identical. This, with very little change, gives you compile time type safety and much cleaner code than your example above.

Your only other option would be to create a non-generic subclass of `List` that implements each of the generic types you want to deal with, and use a different subclass for each type - but I really can't see any situation in which that would be preferable.

Comment: I had thought of defining a custom `List` type, but neglected this thought, because it seemed ridiculous to introduce a whole new type which does the same as the original one, just to avoid ambiguity when calling one singular function. Not precisely your idea at the end of the answer, but along those lines. Well, seems I have no choice but to rename the function, though it is a pain to have a clean class with a bunch of `toPointer` overloads and a single `typeAToPointer`. At least I did not overlook something obvious, so this is my silver lining. Thank you!

Comment: In other languages (ex: Haskell) it's common to alias built-in types. This can provide clarity and reduce the chance of mixing up values that have different semantics, but are represented by the same basic type (ex: weight and height are both floats, but you usually don't want to add them). There's some _theoretical_ beauty in handling this through polymorphism, and I'd definitely _consider_ the idea of mimicking aliases this through distinct non-generic List types, but I think you're right to hold off polluting your codebase until you find >1 case of distinction.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
static FloatPointer typeAToPointer( List< TypeA > list )
{
    return toPointer( list, objectOfTypeA -> /*parse to FloatPointer*/ );
}

static FloatPointer typeBToPointer( List< TypeB > list )
{
    return toPointer( list, objectOfTypeB -> /*parse to FloatPointer*/ );
}

static < T > FloatPointer toPointer( List< T > list, Function< T, FloatPointer > parser ) {
   //do some common code here
   T object = /* extract object from list*/
   FloatPointer pointer = parser.apply( object );
   //do some other common code on pointer 
   return pointer ;
}
```

Here you have one template method toPointer that uses *Function< T, FloatPointer > parser* to map object of some type T to FloatPinter. How it's mapped is specified in concrete toPointer( List< TypeA > list ) methods. For example the objectOfTypeA -> /*parse to FloatPointer*/ could be simply objectOfTypeA -> objectOfTypeA.getFloatPointer().

Edit: as @AndyTurner mentioned, both toPointer methods will make a compilation error due to type erasure. If you operate on lists with correct types on compile time, renaming the methods will do the trick.

Comment: Except you can't, because the erasure of the first two `toPointer` methods is the same, so it won't compile.

Comment: Yeah, sadly as @Andy Turner mentioned, this results in the same problem I am having. The compiler will understand the two signatures of the first two functions to be equivalent.

Comment: @AndyTurner oh I didn't notice. I would rename the methods typeAToPointer() and typeBToPointer() and solve the issue if you know what type of list you have at all times.